# JSON Store support for Android N - IBM Mobile First Platform 7.1.0

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have developed an application in IBM Mobile First Platform 7.1.0. targeting Android and IPhone devices with JSON Store Feature.

*Android N* has been released recently, and *JSON Store feature is not working* as expected (the same is working fine in all other version). I have tried to install the app in *nexus 5X android N device*

> Reference:
>   https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/05/mobilefirst-platform-compatibility-for-android-n/
>
> https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/14/support-plan-for-android-n/
>
> As explained in above reference, fix pack will be released for the
>   support in Android N.

Is there any other way to resolve the above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Contact IBM Support (by opening a PMR) and request said iFix build containing the fix. This fix may already be released - you should look at the latest available iFix in IBM Fix Central website.

Comment: For the recent IBM MFP 8.0 also the JSON Store is not working. Is there any fix pack for the same.

Comment: Yesterday there was a new iFix. Try your luck with it: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/12/06/8-0-ifix-release/